# How to delete an uploaded image with a html button in Django?

Tags: django

How can I delete an uploaded image from my updateview template? I tried using `<input type="checkbox" onchange="submit();" name="{{ object.image }}-clear" id="{{ object.image }}-clear_id">` to remove the image but with no success.

I have `django_cleanup` in `INSTALLED_APPS` so I am just looking for a simple method to remove the image from my object and return to the currrent update view.

**Code:**

models.py:

```
class Report(models.Model):

    image = models.FileField(storage=PublicMediaStorage(), blank=True)
```

forms.py:

```
class ReportCreate(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ReportCreate, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    class Meta:
        model = Report

        fields = ['image']
        widgets = {'image': forms.FileInput(attrs={'onchange': 'submit();'}),}
```

Views.py:

```
class ReportView(LoginRequiredMixin, UserPassesTestMixin, UpdateView):

    model = Report

    template_name = 'myapp/report_update.html'
    form_class = forms.ReportCreate

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.author = self.request.user
        return super().form_valid(form)
```

urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('report/<int:pk>/', ReportView.as_view(), name='report-view'),
]
```

html:

```
<img src="{{ object.image }}"/>
<input type="file" name="image" onchange="submit();" class="fileinput fileUpload form-control-file" id="id_image">
<input type="checkbox" onchange="submit();" name="{{ object.image }}-clear" id="{{ object.image }}-clear_id">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update Report model

```
image = models.ImageField(storage=PublicMediaStorage(), null=True, blank=True)
```

In views.py

```
from django.views.generic import View

class ReportImageDeleteView(View):
    # you can either user POST, PUT or DELETE methods respectively 
    def get(self, request):

        report = Report.objects.get(id=self.kwargs.get('pk'))
        report.image = None
        report.save()

        return render(request, 'your_template.html')

# url
path(
    'report/<int:pk>/delete/',
    ReportImageDeleteView.as_view(),
    name='image-delete'
),
```

in template

```
<input type="checkbox" onchange="clearImage({{ object.id }});" name="{{ object.image }}-clear">

<script>
function clearImage(id) {
    var url = `/report/${id}/delete/`;
    window.location = url; // redirect
}
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks. However, I already have an existing DeleteView that deletes the whole report. When I try to implement your solution it mixes up with the other deleteview and deletes the whole report. I just want to delete the image. Also "object.id" refers to a specific report. How can i get the "image.id"?

Comment: I have updated the answer now, now you can remove the image without deleting the whole report, just by setting the image value to Null.

Comment: +1 works like a charm, thanks!. Only thing I had to change was return render(request, 'your_template.html') to return redirect("/report/"+str(kwargs['pk'])+"/") in order to return to the specific report.

Answer (score 0):

try this
firstly edit your models.py like this so no one can upload any file except photos

```
class Report(models.Model):

    image = models.ImageField(storage=PublicMediaStorage(), blank=True)
```

then in your views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import redirect

 def delete_image(request, pk):
    query = Report.objects.get(pk=id)
    query.delete()
    return redirect("/report/<int:pk>/")
```

then urls.py

```
path('delete_image/(?P<pk>\d+)/', views.delete_image, name='delete_image')
```

and in your html

```
<a href="{% url 'delete_image' image.id %}">Delete</a>
```

Comment: Seeing as the OP is using class-based generic views, you could aim to answer using a CBV such as `django.views.generic.edit.DeleteView`

Comment: Thanks for the answer. However, I get an error saying "'ImageFieldFile' object has no attribute 'id'" when trying to delete the image. I cant seem to get "image.id" to work.

Answer (score 0):

Write an APIView which does this:

views.py

```
class RemoveImageFromReportView(APIView):
    """Removes only the image uploaded from the Report instance."""

    def delete(self, request, *args, **kwargs):

        report = Report.objects.get(id=kwargs['pk'])
        report.image.delete(save=True)
        report.save()
        return Response(data=None)
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path(
        "reports/<int:pk>/",
        views.RemoveImageFromReportView.as_view(),
        name="remove_image_from_instance",
    ),
]
```

On the html part. When the user clicks the delete image button make a `ajax` request to this endpoint with the instance id. Note that the api request made must be a `DELETE` method

If you want to delete the entire Report instance then [use this link](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views/#destroyapiview).